# OnClickListener will not detect click on rectangle?

Tags: java, android, view, onclicklistener, rectangles

I have two rectangles with each rectangle taking up half of the screen exactly and I am trying to detect clicks on the rectangles.

### **What I tried:**

I tried to set an OnClickListener on both rectangles but when I click either rectangle a click will not be detected. I was very sure it wasn't detecting a click so I logged inside the listeners and that confirmed my suspicions; the listeners weren't being entered and therefore no click was being detected.

*Here is where I declare the listeners in my activity:*

```
topRectangle = new Rectangle(this, 0, 0, mScrWidth, mScrHeight/2, 0xC757FF57);
    bottomRectangle = new Rectangle(this,0, mScrHeight /2, mScrWidth, mScrHeight, 0xDEFF5845 );

    mainView.addView(mLine);
    mLine.invalidate();

    mainView.addView(topRectangle);
    topRectangle.invalidate();

    mainView.addView(bottomRectangle);
    bottomRectangle.invalidate();

    View.OnClickListener topListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (topRectangle.getColor() == 0xC757FF57 /*Green*/) {

                if (!isGameStarted) {
                    isGameStarted = true;
                }

                topRectangle.setColor(0xDEFF5845);

                if (movingUp) {
                    movingUp = false;
                } else {
                    movingUp = true;
                }
            }
            else if (topRectangle.getColor() == 0xDEFF5845 /*Red*/) {
                /*Player Dies*/
            }
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener bottomListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bottomRectangle.getColor() == 0xC757FF57 /*Green*/) {
                bottomRectangle.setColor(0xDEFF5845);

                if (movingUp) {
                    movingUp = false;
                } else {
                    movingUp = true;
                }
            }
            else if (bottomRectangle.getColor() == 0xDEFF5845 /*Red*/) {
                /*Player Dies*/
            }
        }
    };

    topRectangle.setOnClickListener(topListener);

    bottomRectangle.setOnClickListener(bottomListener);

    topRectangle.setClickable(true);
    bottomRectangle.setClickable(true);
```

*Here is the class I have for rectangles:*

```
public class Rectangle extends View {

public float left;
public float top;
public float right;
public float bottom;
public int color;
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public static int[] colorArray = {0xFF949CFF, 0xffeef16b, 0xFFFFAD85, 0xFFAFFF78, 0xFFE3ABFF,
        0xFF7DFFE0, 0xFFFEBC71, 0xFFA877FB, 0xFF62FF8B, 0xFFF99AA1, 0xFFA9FF53,
        0xFFD02A21, 0xFF1D1AD0, 0xFFCED07E, 0xFF60B4FF, 0xFFFFA1E0};


/*Faded Blue, yellow, salmon, green, pink-red, light blue, light orange, purple, teal, pink,
light-green, red, blue, sand, lighter blue, pink*/
public static Random randomGenerator = new Random();


public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    this.color = color;
}


public int getTheBottom() {
    return (int) bottom;
}


public int getTheLeft() {
    return (int) left;
}


public int getTheTop() {
    return (int) top;
}


public int getTheRight() {
    return (int) right;
}

//construct new rectangle object
public Rectangle(Context context, float left, float top, float right, float bottom, int color) {
    super(context);
    //color hex is [transparncy][red][green][blue]
    mPaint.setColor(color);  //not transparent. color is white
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.right = right;
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

//construct new rectangle object
public Rectangle(Context context, float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    super(context);
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.right = right;
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

//qcalled by invalidate()
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);
}

public void setX(float left, float right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

public void setY(float top, float bottom) {
    this.top = top;
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

public int getRectWidth() {
    return (int) (right - left);
}

public int getRectHeight() {
    return (int) (bottom - top);
}

public int getCenterX() {
    return (int) (right + left) / 2;
}

public int getCenterY() {
    return (int) (top + bottom) / 2;
}

}
```

### **What I Have Referenced:**

[OnClickListener won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466054/onclicklistener-wont-work)

[Android: onClickListener does not work as programmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571262/android-onclicklistener-does-not-work-as-programmed)

### **Question:**

Why is no click being detected on the rectangle views?

Answer (score 0):

You have told the view what to do when the user clicks on it but it looks like the view is not currently clickable. Try this:

```
topRectangle = new Rectangle(this, 0, 0, mScrWidth, mScrHeight/2, 0xC757FF57);
topRectangle.setClickable(true);

bottomRectangle = new Rectangle(this,0, mScrHeight /2, mScrWidth, mScrHeight, 0xDEFF5845 );
bottomRectangle.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: I wrote `setClickable` for both rectangles in the last line of the activity code I provided......I solved the problem anyway by using a touch listener instead. Thank you! :)